# class="lazyload" problem data-src problem fix

Tags: html, width

I am checking websites page source inorder to learn how to desing. And I saw a code liike this.

```
<img 
      class="lazyload"
      data-src="//example.com/files/image_{width}x.jpg?v=*****"
      data-widths="[180,360,540,720,900,1000]"
      data-aspectratio="1.1904761904761905"
      data-sizes="auto"
      alt=""
      
      data-image
  >
```

But when I try to integrate it to my store, it does not work. In data-src="//example.com/files/image_{width}x.jpg?v=*****" there is a {width} "tag" (or what its name, idk).
I think the problem is that. Like when I use that "tag" on my website it does not work. But when I use the image url of that website it works. Any idea how can I do the same as that websites code?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on the DOM. You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). But usually it is used to add extra data to an HTML tag to use that data with Javascript.

Now, the {width} on data-src=“//example.com/files/image_{width}x.jpg?v=*****” looks like a variable. I think it’s used to assign one value on the data-widths attribute depending on window size.

Comment: Yes it is used to assing one value on data-widths attribute depending on window size. but it does not work for me. and I do not know why?

Comment: Can you add some code to see?